# How to prevent table header split in TextSharp Pdftable

Tags: itext

I have a dynamic table that will occupy half to full page and a dynamic table after that. The problem is there is lot of space if i move the whole table to a new page sometimes and if i break the table the header alone is in one page and the rest of the content is in the next page sometimes.

I want to know if it is possible to make sure that the page break is not introduced between the table header and the first row of the table.

I am aware of how to do the following,

Prevent the whole table from splitting if there is not enough space in the page and move it to a new page by using

```
KeepTogether = true
```

Allow the table to split but prevent the row from splitting if there is not enough space by using

```
KeepTogether = false;

SplitRows = true;

SplitLate = true;
```

Repeat the table header if the table spans across multiple pages

But i don't want any of these methods. I want to allow the table to split but just not between the header and the first row or the first two rows otherwise. Please any one give some idea to sort out this issue.

Samplepdf:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that can be used to reproduce the problem and tell us which version of iText you are using? I think that you're using an old version of iText. The current version is iText 7.1.3 ([C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) / [Java](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases)). You seem to be using an old version (or a *maintenance* version of an old version). Please upgrade.

Comment: am using iTextSharp-LGPL.4.1.6(open source).

Comment: Too bad, in that case I can't help you because of [these reasons](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). I hope you are informing your customer that you are using a version of iText that is more than 9 years old, and that this version shouldn't be used in a commercial context.

Comment: Thanks for your update.i ll check.